# How can I get the constant from an ODE in python?

Tags: python, numpy, sympy, ode, differential-equations

My task is to calculate the constant from an ODE. So, I don't want to plot the function, I just want to get the result of the differential equation, and after that I need to calculate the c based on this assumption: v0=120 when t0=0.
I have started to implement with help of sympy module, and I get successfully the following result:[120.000000000000 -2.23606797749979/tanh(C1)]
But, after that I have no idea how I could get c1. Is it possible?

```
import inline as inline
import sympy as sp
import numpy as np
from scipy import integrate
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from sympy import *
from sympy import lambdify
t=Symbol('t')
v = map(Function, 'v')
v=Function('v')
k=2
g=10
i=dsolve(Eq( Derivative(v(t), t)+k*v(t)**2, g), v(t))
j=i.subs(v(t),120).subs(t,0).evalf()
print(i)
print(j)
h=j.args
k=np.array(h)
```

Comment: What is the sympy version? The last versions have explicit support for initial conditions. In general, ODE support in sympy is to be considered very experimental, always verify the obtained solution.

Answer (score 2):

If you want the value of `C1` corresponding to the values of a given `t` and `v(t)` you could first solve for it and then substitute in the known values:

```
>>> C1 = [_ for _ in i.free_symbols if _.name == 'C1'][0]
>>> vals = solve(i, C1)
>>> [_.subs(v(t),120).subs(t,0).n(2) for _ in vals]
[-0.019 + 3.1*I, -0.019]
```